# Berlekamp Massey Algorithm for BCH simplified binary version

Tags: matlab, math, error-correction, reed-solomon, bch-code

I am trying to follow Lin, Costello's explanation of the simplified BM algorithm for the binary case in page 210 of chapter 6 with no success on finding the error locator polynomial.
I'm trying to implement it in MATLAB like this:

```
function [locator_polynom] = compute_error_locator(syndrome, t, m, field, alpha_powers)
% 
    % Initial conditions for the BM algorithm
    polynom_length = 2*t;
    syndrome = [syndrome; zeros(3, 1)];
    % Delta matrix storing the powers of alpha in the corresponding place
    delta_rho     = uint32(zeros(polynom_length, 1)); delta_rho(1)=1;
    delta_next    = uint32(zeros(polynom_length, 1));
   
    % Premilimnary values
    n_max = uint32(2^m - 1);

    % Initialize step mu = 1
    delta_next(1) = 1; delta_next(2) = syndrome(1); % 1 + S1*X
    % The discrepancy is stored in polynomial representation as uint32 numbers
    value = gf_mul_elements(delta_next(2), syndrome(2), field, alpha_powers, n_max);
    discrepancy_next = bitxor(syndrome(3), value);
    % The degree of the locator polynomial
    locator_degree_rho  = 0;
    locator_degree_next = 1;
    
    % Update all values
    locator_polynom     = delta_next;
    delta_current       = delta_next;
    discrepancy_rho     = syndrome(1);
    discrepancy_current = discrepancy_next;
    locator_degree_current     = locator_degree_next;
    rho = 0; % The row with the maximum value of 2mu - l starts at 1
    
    for i = 1:t % Only the even steps are needed (so make t out of 2*t)
        if discrepancy_current ~= 0
            % Compute the correction factor 
            correction_factor = uint32(zeros(polynom_length, 1));
            x_exponent = 2*(i - rho);
            if (discrepancy_current == 1 || discrepancy_rho == 1)
                d_mu_times_rho = discrepancy_current * discrepancy_rho;
            else
                alpha_discrepancy_mu        = alpha_powers(discrepancy_current);
                alpha_discrepancy_rho       = alpha_powers(discrepancy_rho);
                alpha_inver_discrepancy_rho = n_max - alpha_discrepancy_rho;
                % The alpha power for dmu * drho^-1 is
                alpha_d_mu_times_rho  = alpha_discrepancy_mu + alpha_inver_discrepancy_rho;
                % Equivalent to aux mod(2^m - 1)
                alpha_d_mu_times_rho  = alpha_d_mu_times_rho - ...
                                  n_max * uint32(alpha_d_mu_times_rho > n_max);
                d_mu_times_rho = field(alpha_d_mu_times_rho);          
            end
            correction_factor(x_exponent+1) = d_mu_times_rho;
            correction_factor = gf_mul_polynoms(correction_factor,...
                                                delta_rho,...
                                                field, alpha_powers, n_max);
            % Finally we add the correction factor to get the new delta
            delta_next = bitxor(delta_current, correction_factor(1:polynom_length));
            
            % Update used data
            l = polynom_length;
            while delta_next(l) == 0 && l>0
                l = l - 1;
            end
            locator_degree_next = l-1;
            % Update previous maximum if the degree is higher than recorded
            if (2*i - locator_degree_current) > (2*rho - locator_degree_rho)
                locator_degree_rho  = locator_degree_current;
                delta_rho           = delta_current;
                discrepancy_rho     = discrepancy_current;
                rho = i;
            end
        else
            % If the discrepancy is 0, the locator polynomial for this step
            % is passed to the next one. It satifies all newtons' equations
            % until now.
            delta_next = delta_current; 
        end

        % Compute the discrepancy for the next step
        syndrome_start_index = 2 * i + 3;
        discrepancy_next     = syndrome(syndrome_start_index); % First value
        for k = 1:locator_degree_next
            value = gf_mul_elements(delta_next(k + 1), ...
                                    syndrome(syndrome_start_index - k), ...
                                    field, alpha_powers, n_max);
            discrepancy_next = bitxor(discrepancy_next, value);
        end
        
        % Update all values
        locator_polynom = delta_next;
        delta_current = delta_next;
        discrepancy_current = discrepancy_next;
        locator_degree_current = locator_degree_next;
    end
end
```

I'm trying to see what's wrong but I can't. It works for the examples in the book, but not always. As an aside, to compute the discrepancy S_2mu+3 is needed, but when I have only 24 syndrome coefficients how is it computed on step 11 where 2*11 + 3 is 25?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the code is ok. I made a different implementation from Error Correction and Coding. Mathematical Methods and gives the same result. My problem is at the Chien Search.

Code for the interested:

```
function [c] = compute_error_locator_v2(syndrome, m, field, alpha_powers)
% 
    % Initial conditions for the BM algorithm
    % Premilimnary values
    N = length(syndrome);
    n_max = uint32(2^m - 1);
    polynom_length = N/2 + 1;
    L = 0; % The curent length of the LFSR
    % The current connection polynomial
    c = uint32(zeros(polynom_length, 1)); c(1) = 1;
    % The connection polynomial before last length change
    p = uint32(zeros(polynom_length, 1)); p(1) = 1;
    l = 1; % l is k - m, the amount of shift in update
    dm = 1; % The previous discrepancy
    for k = 1:2:N % For k = 1 to N in steps of 2
        % ========= Compute discrepancy ==========
        d = syndrome(k);
        for i = 1:L
            aux = gf_mul_elements(c(i+1), syndrome(k-i), field, alpha_powers, n_max);
            d   = bitxor(d, aux);
        end
        
        if d == 0 % No change in polynomial
            l = l + 1;
        else
            % ======== Update c ========
            t = c;
            % Compute the correction factor 
            correction_factor = uint32(zeros(polynom_length, 1));
            % This is d *  dm^-1
            dd_sum = modulo(alpha_powers(d) + n_max - alpha_powers(dm), n_max);
            for i = 0:polynom_length - 1
                if p(i+1) ~= 0
                    % Here we compute d*d^-1*p(x_i)
                    ddp_sum = modulo(dd_sum + alpha_powers(p(i+1)), n_max);
                    if ddp_sum == 0
                        correction_factor(i + l + 1) = 1;
                    else
                        correction_factor(i + l + 1) = field(ddp_sum);
                    end
                end
            end
            % Finally we add the correction factor to get the new locator
            c = bitxor(c, correction_factor);
            
            if (2*L >= k) % No length change in update
                l = l + 1;
            else
                p   = t;
                L   = k - L;
                dm  = d;
                l = 1;
            end
        end
        l = l + 1;
    end
end
```

The code comes from this implementation of the Massey algorithm
[image: Massey's algorithm for BCH binary code]

Comment: I wouldn't classify the BCH Berlekamp Massey algorithm for BCH binary as simpler than one for Reed Solomon. To change the above code from BCH binary to Reed Solomon, change the outer loop to for k = 1 to N in steps of 1 and remove the l = l + 1; (accounts...) at the end of the code. On the systems I tested on, I didn't see much difference in run time. Note - my syndromes calculation does 3 table lookups per message byte per syndrome, which could be reduced from 3 to 1 table lookup with a large lookup table, but the table would not fit in cache, so that probably would not help.